# Construct 2 dynamic audio loading issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio, construct

In my app I need to load mp3 audio files at runtime, the names for these files are obtained from json file.

I have tried several approaches to play these audio files, following approaches have been tried:
1. Using plain Javascript audio tag.
2. By Howler.js in C2
3. jQuery

All these work fine in Chrome & Firefox but in IE it does not work properly. Many times audio does not play at all and at other times its inconsistent.

1. How is IE different that Chrome & Firefox in playing audio ?
2. why does IE fail when Chrome & Firefox work so well ?
3. How can IE be made to work without these audio issues ?

-Thanks
Mahesh

Comment: `why does IE fail when Chrome & Firefox work so well?` I could see that on a T-shirt. Could you post the code of the three methods you have tried.